# Another phrase/word for recovering/rebounding from setbacks?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there a better way of saying "rebound/recover from setbacks" within less than 4 words? Or even a single word for it?

Comment: “Recover from setbacks” is already less than 4 words.

Comment: An adjective describing someone who can recover from setbacks is _resilient_.

Answer (score 2):

Try `bounce back`

: to return quickly to a normal condition after a difficult situation or event

*She bounced back easily from her surgery.*

*After losing the first three games of the series, they bounced back to win their next eight games.*

Source - [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounce%20back)